# Handling Angular 4 events in MVC apps

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, angular, events

We have an user control developed using Angular 4 , which emits events based on user action

We wanted to integrate this  control in ASP.NET MVC application that does not have angular support but has support for jquery ... Is there any way to load the control and capture angular events in jquery and use them.

I went through this article

https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2017/04/10/using-angular-2-components-in-a-non-angular-app/

but could not get much info

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Instead of doing it the hard way, why not try adding Angular to the MVC app? Here's a good start: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43484448/4962764

Comment: We though about that , but we are embedding the control in an legacy  application with lot of jquery plugins and they do not want to make it angular